# Mobile Google translate web version. Hide top bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, translation, google-translate, translate

I am using google translate web interface to translate websites. (mobile)

How can I hide top search form? (highlighted on image)

I use this link to translate webpage to Italian:

```
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=it&u=yandex.ru
```

image:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVSV8.png